# how to url encode expressions of template variable with $interpolate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

I have a variable

> x = "http://example.com?a={{a}}&b={{b}}

This variable is then used in a

> ng-src={{x}}

Therefore it is important for me to url encode the variables a and b.

What i do currently is:

```
var func = $interpolate($scope.x);
            var url = func($scope);
            return  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
```

My problem is that when a or b contains spaces they are not url encoded.

How can i tell the $interpolate function to url encode the variables a and b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `$interpolate` service does evaluates the `{{}}` content and take
>   those value from scope while evaluating scope.

As you want to see the url econded, you are not doing encoding of parameters anywhere. You need to encode your `a` as well as `b` in `{{}}` interpolation using `encodeURIComponent` of javascript. For that you need to create a wrapper method in scope that will call `encodeURIComponent` method and return the encode `URL`, method would be like below.

```
$scope.encodeContent = function(data){
     return encodeURIComponent(data);
}
```

Thereafter your `URL` would look like `http://www.example.com/images.jpg?a={{encodeContent(a)}}&b={{encodeContent(b)}}`

And while attaching it to `src` of `img` tag you need to evaluate interpolation first & then you can make that url as trusted as you are doing now.

**Markup**

```
<img src="{{trustedUrl(x)}}" width="50" height="50"/>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.trustedUrl = function(url){
   var interpolatedUrl = $interpolate(url)($scope)
   return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(interpolatedUrl)
};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VY9eXHiHRbTULjqbZ4On?p=preview)

Comment: @David Michael Gang does you find any issue with this?

Comment: The solution is great and accepted:-) .I found a minor issue with this. This is a template which is filled in by our users in a backoffice, and then instead of a={{a}}&b={{b}} they will have to write  a={{encodeContent(a)}}&b={{encodeContent(b)}}. A solution would be that in the backoffice i make a regular expression to transform a={{a}}&b={{b}} to a={{encodeContent(a)}}&b={{encodeContent(b)}}. What do you think ?